# is there a way to choose the width of a pdf created from a txt file with cupsfilter

Tags: cups

i try to find a command line to convert files .txt to .pdf using a tool that most computer running on mac and linux have, like (i think) cupsfilter. but I can't seem to control the width of the output

I don't understand how cupsfilter choose the format it chould print, like how much characters define the width in the text file, it seems to be 80. But the output of 80 characters width on a A4 size page looks absurdely huge..

if my text looks like this :

```
      |_|                      |_|    | || |_ | |     / . \ |   |
  _ _  _   _ _  _ _ _  _      _ _  _ _| ||  _|| |_    \   / | | |
/_ _ || |\_ _ \| ._ _| \ \  / /| || ( ] || |  |  _ \  / . \ | | |
/_ _ /|_|\_ _ \ \ _ _|  \_/\_/ |_| \ _ _||_|  |_| |_| \_ _/ |_ _|
```

the command `cupsfilter file.txt > file.pdf` will give me the same look, but in huge, in pdf format

however, if my text is longer it will look like this :

```
  _ _   _ _ 
      |_|                      |_|    | || |_ | |    
 / . \ |   |
  _ _  _   _ _  _ _ _  _      _ _  _ _| ||  _|| |_   
 \   / | | |
/_ _ || |\_ _ \| ._ _| \ \  / /| || ( ] || |  |  _ \ 
 / . \ | | |
/_ _ /|_|\_ _ \ \ _ _|  \_/\_/ |_| \ _ _||_|  |_| |_|
 \_ _/ |_ _|
```

I would tel cupsfilter to consider a page width to be more than 80 characters long, or to use another tool  to do that ?